# UWP SpeechRecognizer throw exception:Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am developing UWP and want to use SpeechRecognizer. When I run the application, the first try is right but next tries will throw a System.InvalidOperationException at

`SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();`.

The error message is

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

And another situation is that when I click the button to speak, the function `RecognizeAsync()` seems not to be called and I immediately get the MessageDialog with blank content and the return value of the program is 1(0x1). I don't get exception in this way but if I click the button quickly, it will throw the exception above.

I have searched a lot of pages online but none of them could figure out 
this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my full code

```
public sealed partial class VoiceMainPage : Page
    {
        public VoiceMainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void OnListenAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizer.
            var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

            // Compile the dictation grammar by default.
            await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

            // Start recognition.
            SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();

            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Text spoken");
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to run it in a Thread?

Comment: Do you mean using the RunAsync() function? I have tried to use it after turning to MSDN but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, Thread.Run() or something. Sorry can't help you more, I just know UWP API often required to be run from a background Thread, but have not used SpeechRecognizer yet.

Comment: Okay I will have a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this official [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis). Here is an adaptation of your code reusing part of the github sample :

```
   public class VoiceMainPage
{
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    private CoreDispatcher dispatcher;
    private IAsyncOperation<SpeechRecognitionResult> recognitionOperation;

    public VoiceMainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When activating the scenario, ensure we have permission from the user to access their microphone, and
    /// provide an appropriate path for the user to enable access to the microphone if they haven't
    /// given explicit permission for it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The navigation event details</param>
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the UI thread dispatcher to allow speech status messages to be shown on the UI.
        dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;

        bool permissionGained = await AudioCapturePermissions.RequestMicrophonePermission();
        if (permissionGained)
        {
            // Enable the recognition buttons.                
            await InitializeRecognizer(SpeechRecognizer.SystemSpeechLanguage);
            buttonOnListen.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Permission to access capture resources was not given by the user; please set the application setting in Settings->Privacy->Microphone.
            buttonOnListen.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private async void OnListenAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        buttonOnListen.IsEnabled = false;

        // Start recognition.
        try
        {
            recognitionOperation = speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();
            SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await recognitionOperation;
            // If successful, display the recognition result.
            if (speechRecognitionResult.Status == SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
            {
                // Access to the recognized text through speechRecognitionResult.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle speech recognition failure
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException exception)
        {
            // TaskCanceledException will be thrown if you exit the scenario while the recognizer is actively
            // processing speech. Since this happens here when we navigate out of the scenario, don't try to 
            // show a message dialog for this exception.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException caught while recognition in progress (can be ignored):");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Exception");
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        buttonOnListen.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ensure that we clean up any state tracking event handlers created in OnNavigatedTo to prevent leaks.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation event</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        if (speechRecognizer != null)
        {
            if (speechRecognizer.State != SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
            {
                if (recognitionOperation != null)
                {
                    recognitionOperation.Cancel();
                    recognitionOperation = null;
                }
            }

            speechRecognizer.StateChanged -= SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;

            this.speechRecognizer.Dispose();
            this.speechRecognizer = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize Speech Recognizer and compile constraints.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recognizerLanguage">Language to use for the speech recognizer</param>
    /// <returns>Awaitable task.</returns>
    private async Task InitializeRecognizer(Language recognizerLanguage)
    {
        if (speechRecognizer != null)
        {
            // cleanup prior to re-initializing this scenario.
            speechRecognizer.StateChanged -= SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;

            this.speechRecognizer.Dispose();
            this.speechRecognizer = null;
        }

        // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizer.
        speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(recognizerLanguage);

        // Provide feedback to the user about the state of the recognizer.
        speechRecognizer.StateChanged += SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;

        // Add a web search topic constraint to the recognizer.
        var webSearchGrammar = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.WebSearch, "webSearch");
        speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(webSearchGrammar);

        // Compile the constraint.
        SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult compilationResult = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        if (compilationResult.Status != SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
        {
            buttonOnListen.IsEnabled = false;
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle SpeechRecognizer state changed events by updating a UI component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Speech recognizer that generated this status event</param>
    /// <param name="args">The recognizer's status</param>
    private async void SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged(SpeechRecognizer sender, SpeechRecognizerStateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            MainPage.Current.NotifyUser("Speech recognizer state: " + args.State.ToString(), NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        });
    }
}
```

The button **buttonOnListen** shall have its enable state set to false during the speech recognition procedure to prevent click handler reentrance. In addition it is preferrable to have the SpeechRecognizer object initialized once during page navigation landing (OnNavigatedTo) and dispose it while leaving the page (OnNavigatedFrom)